# Finding the second last order date of a specific set of customers based on their last order date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table (Customers) that has customer ids, order dates and product type
I want to find the second last order date based on their order history.

Table

```
| C.id     | product  || Order_Date |  
| 1        | pens     || 2023-01-09 |  
| 2        | books    || 2022-10-01 |  
| 2        | books    || 2022-07-09 |  
| 3        | toys     || 2022-06-10 |  
| 3        | books    || 2022-05-05 |  
| 3        | books    || 2022-04-04 |
```

`SELECT c.id,product, min(Order_date) FROM customers  Where product = books Group by c.id;`

```
| C.id     | product  || Order_Date |  
| 2        | books    || 2022-10-01 |    
| 3        | books    || 2022-05-05 |
```

What Im trying to get is this

```
| C.id     | product  || Order_Date |
| -------- | -------- || --------   |
| 2        | books    || 2022-07-09 |  
| 3        | toys     || 2022-06-10 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the correct date for customer 3 is 2022-05-05

```
select id, product, order_date
from customers
qualify row_number() over (
    partition by id
    order by order_date desc
) = 2
order by id;
```

| ID | PRODUCT | ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | books | 2022-07-09 |
| 3 | books | 2022-05-05 |